# Python script to extract data from an excel and put it in trees

Tags: python, json, pandas, tree, anytree

I have a python script that extracts data from an excel, more precisely, data from three columns: Finished Good, Parent Part Code and Material Code. The three columns look like this:

```
Material Code    Parent Part Code   Finished Good
M1               P1                 F1
M2               P2                 F2
M3               M2                 F2
M4               P3                 F2
.....
```

Note: Material Code can also be in the Parent Part Code column.

The tree should look like this:

```
F1
  P1
    M1

F2
  P2
    M2
      M3
  P3
    M4
```

The Python script is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from anytree import Node, RenderTree
import json

# Read excel
df = pd.read_excel('excelFile.xlsx')

root_dict = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    finished_good = row['Finished Good']
    parent_part_code = row['Parent Part Code']
    material_code = row['Material Code']
    
    if finished_good not in root_dict:
        # If not, add as root
        root = Node(finished_good)
        root_dict[finished_good] = root
    else:
        # If Finished Good is in the tree, get the root
        root = root_dict[finished_good]

    if parent_part_code in [node.name for node in root.descendants]:
        # If parent node already exists in the tree, find it and add children
        parent_node = [node for node in root.descendants if node.name == parent_part_code][0]
        
        if material_code in [node.name for node in root.descendants]:
            # If Material Code already exists in the tree, find its sub-tree and copy it to the current node
            material_node = [node for node in root.descendants if node.name == material_code][0]
            material_node.parent = parent_node
        else:
            # If Material Code does not exist in the tree, create a new sub-tree
            material = Node(material_code, parent=parent_node)
            while material_code in df['Parent Part Code'].values:
                filtered = df[df['Parent Part Code'] == material_code]
                parent_code = filtered.iloc[0]['Parent Part Code']
                material_code = filtered.iloc[0]['Material Code']
                parent_node = material
                material = Node(material_code, parent=parent_node)
    else:
        # If parent node doesn't exist in the tree, create new sub-tree
        parent_node = Node(parent_part_code, parent=root)
        material = Node(material_code, parent=parent_node)
        while material_code in df['Parent Part Code'].values:
            filtered = df[df['Parent Part Code'] == material_code]
            parent_code = filtered.iloc[0]['Parent Part Code']
            material_code = filtered.iloc[0]['Material Code']
            parent_node = material
            material = Node(material_code, parent=parent_node)

# Print the trees
for root in root_dict.values():
    print(RenderTree(root))

# Save the trees
def node_to_dict(node):
 
    return {
        'name': node.name,
        'children': [node_to_dict(child) for child in node.children]
    }

with open('normTrees.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump({key: node_to_dict(root) for key, root in root_dict.items()}, file)
    print("The trees were successfully saved")
```

The output results are:

```
Node('/10020115HU')
├── Node('/10020115HU/V371')
│   ├── Node('/10020115HU/V371/YG10-30300')
│   ├── Node('/10020115HU/V371/VECTC002')
│   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/V371/VECTC002/YG10-30200')
│   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002')
│   │   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002/YG10-30300')
│   │   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002/SZVIZ')
│   │   │   └── Node('/10020115HU/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002/RVSZALLPOR')
│   │   └── Node('/10020115HU/V371/VECTC002/RVECTC002')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/V371/U100KOCS')
│       └── Node('/10020115HU/V371/U100KOCS/YG10-30300')
├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0')
│   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371')
│   │   └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/YG10-30300')
│   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/RWINNOVERS')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/RSZENNYEZETT')
├── Node('/10020115HU/10020115HU')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/10020115HU/TTK00001HU')
├── Node('/10020115HU/D67AMBR910')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/D67AMBR910/RWINNOVERS')
└── Node('/10020115HU/D67LTRR910')
    ├── Node('/10020115HU/D67LTRR910/RWINNOVERS')
    └── Node('/10020115HU/D67LTRR910/RSECONDUST')
The trees were successfully saved
```

The script does not work as expected because code V371 appears as a child node for Finished Good 10020115HU and as a sub-node for code C00211L0.

I would need the script to be modified so that it displays the tree as follows:

```
Node('/10020115HU')
├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0')
│   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371')
│   │   └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/YG10-30300')
|   |     └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002')
|   |   |    └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/YG10-30200')
      |  └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0//V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002')
│   │   |    │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002/YG10-30300')
│   │   |    │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002/SZVIZ')
│   │   |    │   └── Node('10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002/RVSZALLPOR')
│   │   |    └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/RVECTC002')
│   |   Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/U100KOCS')
│   |     └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/U100KOCS/YG10-30300')
│   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/RWINNOVERS')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/RSZENNYEZETT')
├── Node('/10020115HU/10020115HU')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/10020115HU/TTK00001HU')
├── Node('/10020115HU/D67AMBR910')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/D67AMBR910/RWINNOVERS')
└── Node('/10020115HU/D67LTRR910')
    ├── Node('/10020115HU/D67LTRR910/RWINNOVERS')
    └── Node('/10020115HU/D67LTRR910/RSECONDUST')
```

Comment: Do you accept a solution with another library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your input may list *Parent Part Codes* that (much) later occur as *Material Code* ("V371" is in that case), which means they are not a direct child of the root. If this later occurrence includes a *Parent Part Code* that is new, then a new node is created (unconditionally) for that *Material Code*, and so in this case you have two nodes with the name "V371" in your tree.

It can be quite tedious to do this in one pass. I would suggest doing this in two passes:

1. Create the root node and the nodes for all *Parent Part Codes* (assuming at first that they are direct children of the root)
2. Create the nodes for *Material Codes* (if they don't exist yet as *Parent Part Code* node). Attach each of them to the node we have for the associated *Parent Part Code* (from the first phase).

This looks easier:

```
root_dict = {}
for sweep in range(2):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        finished_good = row['Finished Good']
        parent_part_code = row['Parent Part Code']
        material_code = row['Material Code']
    
        if finished_good not in root_dict:
            root_dict[finished_good] = Node(finished_good), {}
        root, nodes = root_dict[finished_good]
        if parent_part_code not in nodes:
            nodes[parent_part_code] = Node(parent_part_code, parent=root)
        if sweep:
            child = nodes[material_code] if material_code in nodes else Node(material_code)
            child.parent = nodes[parent_part_code]
```

After this has executed, the tree is ready to print. As the above code associates a `nodes` dictionary for each tree, the values of the `root_dict` dictionary are now tuples (pairs), so the loop should extract the root from that tuple:

```
for root, _ in root_dict.values():
    print(RenderTree(root))
```

Output:

```
Node('/10020115HU')
├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0')
│   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371')
│   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/YG10-30300')
│   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002')
│   │   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/YG10-30200')
│   │   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002')
│   │   │   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002/YG10-30300')
│   │   │   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002/SZVIZ')
│   │   │   │   └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/VNCTC002/RVSZALLPOR')
│   │   │   └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/VECTC002/RVECTC002')
│   │   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/U100KOCS')
│   │   │   └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/U100KOCS/YG10-30300')
│   │   └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/V371/YG10-30300')
│   ├── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/RWINNOVERS')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/C00211L0/RSZENNYEZETT')
├── Node('/10020115HU/10020115HU')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/10020115HU/TTK00001HU')
├── Node('/10020115HU/D67AMBR910')
│   └── Node('/10020115HU/D67AMBR910/RWINNOVERS')
└── Node('/10020115HU/D67LTRR910')
    ├── Node('/10020115HU/D67LTRR910/RWINNOVERS')
    └── Node('/10020115HU/D67LTRR910/RSECONDUST')
```